# Raycast 2D ricochet in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics, raycasting

I'm new to Raycasting so I might be going about this in a bad way, but I would to send a raycast outward to direction a gameobject is facing, bounce off the first object it hits and go a short distance before disappearing.

As far as I can tell there is no built in function for reflecting raycasts in Unity, so I have been trying to generate a another raycast where the first one hits but my luck hasn't been going well. Here's what I have so far:

```
public Gameobject firePoint; // I have an object attached to my main object that I use as a point of origin

void DrawLazer()
{
    Vector2 origin = new Vector2(firePoint.transform.position.x, firePoint.transform.position.y);
 
        Vector2 direction = transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up);
 
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(origin, direction, 10f);
        Debug.DrawLine(origin, direction *10000, Color.black);
        if (hit)
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit: " + hit.collider.name);
            var whatWeHit = new Vector2(hit.transform.position.x, hit.transform.position.y);
            var offset = whatWeHit + hit.point;
            offset.y = 0;
 
            RaycastHit2D hit2 = Physics2D.Raycast(offset, Vector3.Reflect(direction, hit.normal) * -10000);
 
            if (hit2)
            {              
                Debug.DrawLine(offset, -Vector3.Reflect(direction, hit.normal) * -10000);
            }
        }
}
```

I call DrawLaxer(); in update.

[image: Current Results]

This current script is sort of able to generate a 2nd raycast, however as you can see, the first raycast still does not stop when it hits something, and more importantly while this solution works well when it hits a flat object on a horizontal plane. But if it hits on object on a vertical or diagonal plane it applys several calculations to the wrong axis:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You post some text with a piece of code, whats the question here? whats wrong with the code?

Comment: @sommmen I've updated my OP with some screenshots and more detail, does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example monobehavior that uses Vector2.Reflect and SphereCast.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ReflectionExample : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject firePoint;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        DrawPredictionDisplay();
    }


    private void DrawPredictionDisplay()
    {

        Vector2 origin = firePoint.transform.position; //unity has a built in type converter that converts vector3 to vector2 by dropping the z component

        Vector2 direction = firePoint.transform.up;

        float radius = 1.0f;

        RaycastHit2D distanceCheck = Physics2D.Raycast(origin, direction);

        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.CircleCast(origin, radius, direction);


        Debug.DrawLine(origin, direction * 10000, UnityEngine.Color.black);
        DrawCircle(origin, 1.0f, UnityEngine.Color.black);

        if (hit)
        {

            origin = hit.point + (hit.normal * radius);
            direction = Vector2.Reflect(direction, hit.normal);

            hit = Physics2D.CircleCast(origin, radius, direction);

            Debug.DrawLine(origin, direction * 10000, UnityEngine.Color.blue);
            DrawCircle(origin, 1.0f, UnityEngine.Color.blue);
        }
    }


    private void DrawCircle(Vector2 center, float radius, UnityEngine.Color color)
    {
        Vector2 prevPoint = new Vector2(Mathf.Sin(0f), Mathf.Cos(0f));

        for (float t = 0.1f; t < 2 * Mathf.PI; t = t + 0.1f)
        {
            var nextPoint = new Vector2(Mathf.Sin(t), Mathf.Cos(t));

            Debug.DrawLine(center + prevPoint, center + nextPoint, color);

            prevPoint = nextPoint;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: On line 10 it says `RaycastHit2D` does not contain a definition for `contacts`. Am I missing a possible dependency?

Comment: Oh i think its just hit.normal

Comment: Now it says `Reflect` takes 3 arguments.

Comment: Okay, I spent a few hours and from your code I managed to make this: https://pastebin.com/pG0GgfBY (Example of how it's working for me: https://imgur.com/a/lUDuUh4)
I creates a Raycast, and then properly creates the illusion of reflection with a 2nd Raycast, however this code only works if the object you are hitting is perfectly flat on a horizontal plane. How can we make it dynamic so that it accounts for rotation of the object we hit?

Comment: The hit.point is already in world space, as is the hit.normal, so you don't need to offset by the transform.  Just use hit.point.  I'll update my answer based on your new code.

Comment: Ah, okay. Your code appears to work perfectly (https://imgur.com/a/RIEZRJM). Before I mark your answer as correct though, I have a relevant question to ask: It appears that when an object is instantiated from the same `firepoint` variable that the raycast is generated from, everything works perfectly (https://imgur.com/a/BobO5Lv). But when the object the way fired bounces, it ends up at the same angle but slightly lower than the raycast because the object is wider than the raycast (https://imgur.com/a/D1Je4vK). Is there a way to slightly offset the position in which the second raycast is

Comment: generated? That way we can account for the object being wider than the raycast and therefore hitting the raycast sooner than expected?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the `Raycast2D.CircleCast`  You will need to offset the reflected ray's start position by the hit.normal * radius.     But.. if you are trying to simply make a ball bounce off a wall, you could give the ball a rigidbody2d component and a circlecollider component and then just set the rigidbody2d's velocity

Comment: Forgive me but I'm new to Raycasting, a quick search of `CircleCast` shows it's under `Physics2D`. Could you give me an example of what you talking about would look like? For the the record, I already have the ball bouncing on it's own, what I'm trying to way on it a heads up display for the player to see where the ball is going to bounce, I intend to instantiate dots along the raycast line in a similar fashion to that of Angry Birds minus the arch (https://angrybirds.fandom.com/wiki/Slingshot?file=Sling.PNG).

Comment: Ah, yea Physics2D.CircleCast is the one.    Another approach to implement a preview arch is to do like in this blog post https://forum.unity.com/threads/2d-physics-manual-simulation-simulation-groups-multiple-worlds.466501/  The overall strategy is to run a second copy of the world calling Physics.Simulate() in a loop and recording the position of the invisible ball in the other copy of the world.

Comment: Okay, I can look that other way of doing it in the near future, for now though I'd like to at least make an attempt at using raycasts as I need to be learning how to use them anyway. Based on the documentation I have tried static RaycastHit2D CircleCast(origin, .75f, direction, predictionMask);` but no matter what I do I continue to get the error 'Local Function CircleCast(origin, ?) must be declared a body because it is not marked static extern'. The doc's say it takes in origin, radius, direction, and layerMask. What am I missing?

Comment: Its saying you need to do Physics2D.CircleCast instead of just CircleCast

Comment: Okay, After trying `RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.CircleCast(origin, .75f, direction, predictionMask);` I get this odd result with them both originating at firepoint (https://imgur.com/a/0Cm5XC8).

Comment: The 2nd raycast needs to have its origin set to something like hit.point + hit.normal * radius

Comment: `RaycastHit2D hit2 = Physics2D.CircleCast(hit.point + hit.normal * .75f, .75f, Vector2.Reflect(direction, hit.normal), predictionMask);` Did not appear to change anything but I'll note that my only way of knowing what it's doing is based on the Debug.Drawline, is there any way for me to test `Physics2D.CircleCast` with Debug.Drawline?

Comment: After some more testing I got this to work (https://pastebin.com/JKJAXdM6). But it seems to have so odd quirks, if you fire at a harder angle it works flawlessly (https://imgur.com/a/Uo7MsJ0). But if you bounce at a lower angle it becomes inaccurate (https://imgur.com/a/RsceHGL), and this issue become progressively worse based on the angle. Do you know of anything that would cause this?

Comment: I think its because the circle's radius is 10, but when you offset the second ray's origin, you don't multiply the hit normal by 10

Comment: CircleCast allows you to set the radius for the raycast, should I set the radius for multiply hit.normal by the radius? Another issue I've run into since I made my last post is that if I make both both raycasts a CircleCast both colliders add onto each other the the origin for the second raycast becomes double what it should be, but if I only make 1 raycast a CircleCast, then one of them ends up having an issue where because they don't account for the radius of the projectile, they end up being inaccurate if you fire at corners as they projectile hits and reflects off a wall while the raycast

Comment: didn't predict it because of it not looking for radius.

Comment: I hope this helps clear it up https://imgur.com/a/0Skagx8  You need to start at hit.point + hit.normal * radius because the second circlecast should start at the center of the circle, but the hitpoint is on the edge of the circle.   To find the center of the circle, we know that the normal is perpendicular to the thing the circle hit, so we can use it to find the direction from the wall to the center.  Then we multiply the direction vector by the distance from the hit point (the edge of the circle) to the center.. which is the circle's radius.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, it's helped me to debug a bit of what's going on. It may just be my inexperience in raycasting, but from my perspective what your saying is easier said then done. My current code based on your explanation: https://pastebin.com/79QFdLtW causes it to do things like this regardless of the radius I set it (https://imgur.com/a/JkE47GD). Forgive me, but could you try to give me a better example of how that would work in code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215915/discussion-between-leo-bartkus-and-jhon-piper).